# Serialize inherited property declared new with Json.Net doesn't work

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

[Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) has no problem serializing an overridden property in a child class.

```
public override ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

But if I try to use `new` on the property, the serialization fails. There's no exception; `Persons` are just never serialized.

```
public new ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

Why is this?

(This example doesn't make much sense, I know. It's only an example. The goal later is to be able to change datatype of the property `public new ICollection<PersonDto> Persons { get; set; }`)

Comment: What class is the property defined in? And in what class do you define a `new` property with the same name? And what class do you serialize? You cannot serialize to the base class if you define the property as `new`: the `Persons` property of the base class is (depending on the rest of your code) simply not initialized, or null, or an empty collection, while the `Persons` property of the derived class will not be serialized, as it's not seen as part of the base class.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Wouldn't using custom converter for `Person` make more sense?

Comment: @svick I don't know what a custom converter is. Please enlight me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered a simpler way to solved this without having to create a custom `JsonConverter`

If you put the attribute `JsonProperty` over the property it works.

```
[JsonProperty]
public new ICollection<PersonDto> Persons { get; set; }
```

I don't know why Json.Net needs the attribute here. Normally it serializes everything that isn't decorated with `JsonIgnore`. If someone knows, you're welcome to drop a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this because you want to specify how exactly will be `Person` serialized to JSON, I think a better solution would be to use a custom `JsonConverter`. The converter could look something like this:

```
class PersonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var person = (Person)value;
        serializer.Serialize(
            writer,
            new
            {
                Name = person.LastName,
                Age = (int)(DateTime.Now - person.BirthDate).TotalDays / 365
            });
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Person);
    }
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, new PersonConverter())
```